# Problema com upload em PHP

Tags: php, upload

Em um input do type file, não esta sendo gerado o arquivo tmp.

esta e a array gerada pelo PHP

```
Array ( [name] => desin3.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpE0D5.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 30420 )
```

porém o arquivo `phpE0D5.tmp` não é criado na pasta `xampp\tmp` gerando um erro no método

```
   move_uploaded_file
```

erro:

```
Warning (2): move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a    directory [APP\Controller\DocumentsController.php, line 184]
Warning (2): move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpE0D5.tmp' to 'C:\xampp\htdocs\site\app\UploadFiles\1' [APP\Controller\DocumentsController.php, line 184]
```

Comment: O seu form está com o: enctype="multipart/form-data" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pela descrição do erro, o problema é que você está passando somente o diretório como segundo parâmetro para `move_uploaded_file`. Você precisa passar um caminho completo, incluindo o nome do arquivo no local de destino.

Answer (score 3):

Tenta ativar o [error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.error-reporting.php) para verificar o que está acontecendo de errado, ou testa a permissão com:

```
if (!is_writeable('uploads/' . $_FILES['image']['name'])) {
   die("Cannot write to destination file");
}
```

Comment: então quanto a autorização para escrever no arquivo destino está ok , o problema e que não e criado o arquivo .tmp